# WPF: How do I refer to an application resource textblock within any given window?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I am fairly new to WPF.  I understand the concept of defining global application resources to which I can refer throughout the application.  I see I can define a textblock under application resources but can't seem to see how to refer to it within a window.

In the Application.Resources I have the following code:

```
<TextBlock x:Key="ABC_Copyright" Background="Beige" Text="Copyright 2016 ABC Company" />
```

How to I construct a new textblock in any given window that refers back to the "ABC_Copyright" application resource?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We define it as a style;

```
<Style x:Key="ABC_Copyright" TargetType="TextBlock">
   <Setter Property="Background" Value="Beige"/>
   <Setter Property="Text" Value="Copyright 2016 ABC Company"/>
</Style>
```

Then we use it at whatever instance we need to;

```
<TextBlock Style="{StaticResource ABC_Copyright}"/>
```

Hope this helps, cheers.

Comment: No prob, glad you got a remedy.

Answer (score 0):

Create a `ResourceDictionary` where you want to store and just put your your `Resource Dictionary` name as the source of `ResourceDictionary` in the `App.xaml`

```
           <Application.Resources>
            <ResourceDictionary>
                <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                    <ResourceDictionary Source="Your Resource Dictionary Name"/>
                </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            </ResourceDictionary>
         </Application.Resources>
```

Now in `ResourceDictionary`style your `textbolck`that can be accessible from any other palces like that,

```
<Style x:Key="TxtStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
        <Setter Property="Text" Value="Copyright 2016 ABC Company"/>
    </Style>
```

Now refer your `textblock` to the styled `textblock`

```
<TextBlock x:Key="ABC_Copyright" Background="Beige" Style="{StaticResource TxtStyle}"/>
```

Comment: If you'd had just moved his `x:Key` to the style and used it as the resource you'd have got it.